# Merge documents method in apache pdf box does not close input streams, is this normal?

Tags: pdfbox

I'm using pdfbox to merge a list of documents. Merge works perfectly well but after it's done, I try to delete the document in windows and I get this error telling me the file can't be deleted.

[image]

I know how to interpret the bug. It means the stream has not been closed in my java program. Then then I looked at the `mergeDocuments` in pdfbox api and I saw that sources files (in the object called `sit`) are not closed. That's why I am wondering, do you think it's a bug (and the correction is the following that I've put in the method) or do you think I need to close my input streams after calling the `mergeDocuments` methods ?

```
public void mergeDocuments(boolean useScratchFiles) throws IOException
{
    PDDocument destination = null;
    InputStream sourceFile;
    PDDocument source;
    if (sources != null && sources.size() > 0)
    {
        ArrayList<PDDocument> tobeclosed = new ArrayList<PDDocument>();

        try
        {
            Iterator<InputStream> sit = sources.iterator();
            destination = new PDDocument(useScratchFiles);

            while (sit.hasNext())
            {
                sourceFile = sit.next();
                source = PDDocument.load(sourceFile, useScratchFiles);
                tobeclosed.add(source);
                appendDocument(destination, source);
            }
            if (destinationStream == null)
            {
                destination.save(destinationFileName);
            }
            else
            {
                destination.save(destinationStream);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (destination != null)
            {
                destination.close();
            }
            for (PDDocument doc : tobeclosed)
            {
                doc.close();
            }
            // begin fix
            for (InputStream sourceToClose : sources)
            {
                sourceToClose.close();
            }                
            // endfix
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2911 . I see this as a bug because one can also call addSource() with a File object and then there would be no way for the caller to close the inputstream. I need to think about this somewhat.

Comment: It has been fixed per the "you close what you open" rule, a snapshot build should be available soon here:
https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/1.8.11-SNAPSHOT/
So for you it means you have to close the streams yourself. Or use File objects.